# GNU Make: Batching multiple targets in single command invocation

Tags: makefile, build, gnu

Consider the following setup:

```
$ touch 1.src 2.src 3.src
$ cat Makefile
%.dst: %.src
    @convert -o "$@" "$<"
```

We can compile our `.src` files into `.dst` files by running `make 1.dst 2.dst 3.dst` which calls the `convert` (just a placeholder) tool three times.

This setup is fine if there is little overhead in calling `convert`. However, in my case, it has a startup penalty of a few seconds for every single call. Luckily, the tool can convert multiple files in a single call while paying the startup penalty only once, i.e. `convert -o '{}.dst' 1.src 2.src 3.src`.

Is there a way in GNU make to specify that multiple src files should be batched into a single call to `convert`?
**Edit**: To be more precise, what feature I am looking for: Say that `1.dst` is already newer than `1.src` so it doesn't need to be recompiled. If I run `make 1.dst 2.dst 3.dst`, I would like GNU make to execute `convert -o '{}.dst' 2.src 3.src`.

A quick and dirty way would be creating a `.PHONY` rule that simply converts all src files to dst files but that way I would convert every src file each and every time. Further more, specifying dst files as prerequisites in other rules would also no longer be possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. When a single file comes out from another single file, it can be run effectively in parallel when using `make -j`. Making multiple targets from multiple files in one step is clunky (as you can see from proposed answers), `Makefile` gets more complex and harder to maintain and probably you will hit different corner cases where it will become a bottleneck in a different way. I would consider whether reducing startup overhead is worth future maintenance. Maybe a simple parallel `make` would suffice instead?

Comment: I'm actually using `make -j` wherever I can. The issue with the `convert` tool is that it takes like 3 seconds to start up and less than a second to compile the source. Even if I run it in parallel, it spends a lot of time on the same startup process over and over again.  
I'm not sure if it's possible to reduce startup overhead. The tool is written in python and probably spends that startup time in the interpreter.

Comment: @raspy - What is the canonical, correct way to do this then? Should you define an individual Makefile rule for every target you want to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have GNU make 4.3 or above, you can use [grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html) like this:

```
DST_FILES = 1.dst 2.dst 3.dst
SRC_FILES = $(_DST_FILES:.dst=.src)

all: $(DST_FILES)

$(DST_FILES) &: $(SRC_FILES)
        convert -o '{}.dst' $?
        @touch $(DST_FILES)
```

If your `convert` is only updating some of the targets then you need the explicit `touch` to update the rest.

Here's a way to do it with passing a goal on the command line that might work; change `DST_FILES` to:

```
DST_FILES := $(or $(filter %.dst,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),1.dst 2.dst 3.dst)
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks clean! There's one thing that disturbs me: If I run `make 2.dst`, it will compile all src files (which are newer than their corresponding dst files) although I only asked make to compile 2.dst. Is this fixable?

Comment: Are you sure you have GNU make 4.3?  I can't reproduce that behavior.  I'll add an example of what I did.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you run with a goal target.  Yes, you're right, it will always build all the targets (that's what _grouped targets_ means).  If you don't want this behavior you can't use this solution.  You didn't, of course, list that as a requirement in your question :)

Comment: That's correct, I wasn't explicit about that. It's not that much of an issue but do you know of a simple solution to that problem?

Comment: Hm.  Maybe, it depends on what else your makefile needs to do.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Welcome.  Be sure to add a comment or two into your makefile describing what is happening.  Future readers (including your future self) will thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way in GNU make to specify that multiple src files should be batched into a single call to `convert`?

It is possible, but messy, to write `make` rules for build steps that produce multiple targets with a single run of the recipe, such that the recipe is executed just once if any of the targets needs to be updated.  However, you clarify that

> [if] `1.dst` is already newer than `1.src` [, and] I run `make 1.dst 2.dst 3.dst`, I would like GNU make to execute `convert -o '{}.dst' 2.src 3.src`.

.  That's a slightly different problem.  You can use the `$?` automatic variable in a recipe to get the prerequisites that are newer than the rule's target, but for that to serve the purpose, you need a rule with a *single* target.

Here's one slightly convoluted way to make it work:

```
DST_FILES = 1.dst 2.dst 3.dst
SRC_FILES = $(DST_FILES:.dst=.src)

$(DST_FILES): dst.a
        ar x $< $@

dst.a: $(SRC_FILES)
        convert -o '{}.dst' $?
        x='$?'; ar cr $@ $${x//src/dst}
```

The `dst.a` archive serves as the one target with all the .src files as prerequisites, so as to provide a basis for use of `$?`.  Additionally, it provides a workaround for the problem that whenever that target is updated, it becomes newer than all the then-existing .dst files: .dst files that are out of date with respect to the archive but not with respect to the corresponding .src file are extracted from the archive instead of being rebuilt from scratch.

Comment: Note `$${x//src/dst}` is a bash-ism that is not portable: if you want to use this you need to add `SHELL = /bin/bash` to your makefile.

Comment: I don't really see the need for the `ar` stuff.  Why not just change the recipe from `ar x $< $@` to just `touch $@` and change `dst.a` to `.sentinel` or something to hide it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like when making only a subset of the destination files, e.g. `make 2.dst` it will still compile all source files, is that correct? Is there a way around that?